# Git branch without current file changes

Tags: git

If there are some changes to a few files on master and I create a branch, is it possible for that branch to not include the currently edited files on master branch?

Like a clean branch from the last commit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The branch itself won't include local uncommitted changes, but they will remain in your working tree.

You can stash them (see `git help stash`) to obtain a clean working tree.

Comment: Thanks Roman! Forgot about stash. Could get complicated if you do too many of them though. Worked great for what I needed it for though.